# What is the reasoning behind the negation definition in Intuitionistic Logic Forcing and Set Theory Forcing?

Tags: logic, model-theory, forcing, intuitionistic-logic

In Kunen page 96 - of 10th impression 2006:

(p $\Vdash^* \neg A) \iff $ $\forall q \leq p \; \neg \; (q  \Vdash^*  A)$

Similarly in https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/LogicStudyGuide.pdf on page 97 it states :

(k $\Vdash$ ¬A) $\iff$  for any k′ such that k ≤ k′,  $\neg \;$ (k′ $\Vdash$ A)

In Cohen "Set Theory and the Continuum Hypothesis" Cohen states on page 117:

(P forces $\neg $ A) $\iff$ $\forall Q \supseteq P \; \neg \; (Q$  forces  A)

All these definitions are the same (taking account of the definitions of $\leq$ and $\geq$), so taking the Intuitionistic definition - my question is

**"What is the purpose and reasoning behind the choice of the definition of the right to left implication :**

$(k \Vdash ¬A) \Longleftarrow  \forall k′ \geq k \;  \neg \; (k′ \Vdash A) \tag{1}$

**or equivalently its contrapositive (using classical logic in the Metatheory defining the forcing relation) :**

$ \neg \; (k \Vdash ¬A) \Longrightarrow  \exists k′ \geq k \; (k′ \Vdash A) \tag{1a}$

I ask because it appears that :

(i) The right to left definition in equation (1) doesn't seem Intuitionistic and looks to be a 'back door' to the ($ A \lor \neg A$) formula, since it is a "failure to find a ($k' \geq k \; k' \Vdash A$)"  implies that "$(k \Vdash ¬A)$". However why can't there exist a k' $\geq$ k that has $(k' \Vdash ¬A)$, and both $(k \Vdash ¬A)$  and $(k \Vdash A)$  be not be derivable, e.g. if there isn't enough information in k to force $\neg$ A or force A?

(ii) Cohen shows that equation (1a) leads to forcing becoming negation complete i.e. :

$$ \forall k \; \forall A \; (\exists k' \geq k) : (k' \Vdash A) \; OR \;  (k' \Vdash \neg A) $$ However I thought Intuitionistic logic wasn't negation complete (though I couldn't find anything on the web relating Intuitionistic logic and negation completeness)

(iii) Whenever $ k_0 \leq k_1 \leq k_2 ...$ and there is a $k_n \Vdash \neg A$ then :

If we assume forcing is consistent, $\forall k_i \geq k_0 \; \neg \; (k_i \Vdash A) $ will hold and therefore using equation (1) then $$(k_n \Vdash \neg A) \implies \forall k \geq k_0 \; (k \Vdash \neg A) \; $$ which doesn't look 'right' if its correct.

Similarly if there is a $k_n \Vdash A$ then :

If we assume forcing is consistent, $\forall k_i \geq k_0 \; \neg \; (k_i \Vdash \neg A) $ will hold and therefore using equation (1) then $$(k_n \Vdash A) \implies \forall k \geq k_0 \; (k \Vdash \neg \neg A) \; $$ which also doesn't look 'right' if its correct.

Indeed $k_0$ would be able to force the appropriate $\neg A$ or $\neg(\neg A)$ for all formulae A and so would it fall foul of the Godel Incompleteness theorems ?

(iv) I couldn't derive equation (1) from the assumption of negation completeness, I got instead, with no other assumptions :

$$ \exists k'' \geq k : (k'' \Vdash ¬A) \Longleftarrow  \forall k′ \geq k \;  \neg \; (k′ \Vdash A)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question (i) & (iii) Answer :**

See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/why-is-intuitionistic-negation-nonconstructive

Intuitionism primarily addresses proved truths. This means proved truths continue into the future [$p \Vdash A \implies \forall q \geq p \text{ }q \Vdash A$]. But "not proved truth" goes the other way : if $\neg (p \Vdash A)$ then [$\neg (p \Vdash A) \implies \forall q \leq p \text{ } \neg (q \Vdash A)$], i.e. if it hasn't been proved to be true now, it can't have been proved before.

Also note that the design of forcing is intended to mimic the behaviour of models, via the Taski truth definition :

$$ M \models \neg A \iff \neg [M \models A]$$

and taking the contrapositive

$$ \neg (M \models \neg A) \iff [M \models A] \tag{0}$$

If we have a model M[G] that includes a set G with elements $g_i$, the Tarski truth definition, like Forcing, is based upon assessing the truth of an expression A by assessing all its sub expressions. If we use the compactness theorem, for ease, using Enderton "A Mathematical Introduction to Logic", 2nd Edition, for sentential logic, page 60, Corollary 17A :

If $\Sigma$ is any collection of well formed formulas (it could be, for example { $p_1 \in G$ , $p_2 \in G$ ... }), then the following is equivalent to the Compactness Theorem :

$$\Sigma \models \varphi \text{  } \iff \text{  } \exists \text{ finite } \Sigma_0 \subseteq \Sigma : \Sigma_0 \models \varphi \tag{i} $$

So taking equation (0) and converting it to the compactness form using (i):

$$ \neg (M[G] \models \neg A) \iff [M[G] \models A] \iff [\exists \text{ finite subset of G, } \color{blue}{P}  : M[ \color{blue}{P}] \models A] \tag{ii}$$

So the intention of Equation (1a) in the Question is to mimic the form of Equation (ii):

$$\neg \text{ } (k \Vdash ¬A) \Longrightarrow  \exists k′ \geq k \text{ } (k′ \Vdash A) \tag{1a}$$

**Question (iv) Answer :**

In fact the following :

$$(k \Vdash ¬A) \iff  \forall k′ \geq k \text{ }  \neg \text{ } (k′ \Vdash A) \tag{1}$$

**IS** equivalent to

$$\exists k' \geq k : (k' \Vdash ¬A) \iff \forall k'' \geq k \text{ }  \neg \text{ } (k'' \Vdash A) \tag{iv}$$

but it just doesn't look like it is. The key point to realise is that the expression $k \Vdash A$ is 'really' a different way of writing its real meaning of "$ \Vdash (k) = A$" i.e. just like a function F of one variable k would be written "F(k) = A", but here with $\Vdash$ being the same as F. Since $k \Vdash$ can produce a set of expressions, then if the range is split into sets of expressions {A,B,C,...}, then $\Vdash$ can still be considered to be a function.

It is ***very*** important to recognise that $k \Vdash A$ does NOT mean anything like $k \implies A$. Indeed k itself may not even be directly used. In the most general case, k could just be used as a placeholder in "an expression that uses in some way some other elements k' $\geq$ k - or even k' $\leq$ k. So thinking of "$\Vdash(k) = A$" as a function helps to understand what that general meaning is.

*To prove equation (1) $\iff$ equation (iv) :*

Note firstly that -

$$[\forall k'' \geq k \text{ }  \neg \text{ } (k'' \Vdash A)] \iff [\forall k'' \geq k \text{ }  \neg \text{ } (\exists k''' \geq k'' (k''' \Vdash A))] \tag{2}$$

Also note that using (1) and from Question (i) answer that unproved/proved truths propagate backwards/forwards :

$$\exists k' \geq k \text{ }  (k' \Vdash ¬A) \iff  \forall k′' \geq k' \text{ } \neg (k'' \Vdash A)  \iff  \forall k'' \geq k \text{ } \neg (k'' \Vdash A) \iff (k \Vdash ¬A) \text{ } \square \text{   } \tag{3} $$

In fact we can write (iv) in the same form as (1), using (2) to rewrite the r.h.s. if we define a new function $\Vdash'$ by :

$$(k \Vdash' A) \iff  \exists k' \geq k : (k' \Vdash A) \tag{4}$$

Then (iv) becomes :

$$(k \Vdash' ¬A) \iff  \forall k′ \geq k \text{ }  \neg \text{ } (k′ \Vdash' A) \tag{5}$$

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that you're putting the cart before the horse, here. Forcing follows a very snappy theme - "how do generic objects behave?" - and the behavior of negation in forcing is really *inhereted from* the basic nature of the background mathematics. When we view forcing "intrinsically" in this way, there's no surprising definition of the behavior of negation but rather a *provable consequence* of a very natural definition of forcing that makes no reference to syntax at all.

(This is certainly **not** the only way to approach the problem, but I think it's the one that makes things clearest.)

---

Consider the following topological version of forcing **(and skip to the end of this answer - the section starting "At this point ..." - for the connection between this material and forcing as usually presented!)**: we have a topological space $\mathcal{T}=(X,\tau)$ and a collection $\mathscr{P}$ of properties of points that we care about called ... "properties." We start by asking about the "generic" behavior of points in $\mathcal{T}$:

> Q1: For which properties $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$ is the set $$S_\varphi:=\{x\in X: \varphi(x)\}$$ $\tau$-comeager?

(Why do we care about comeager behavior rather than all-of-$X$ behavior? Well, experience from a number of areas in mathematics - including algebraic geometry, incidentally - suggests that allowing *a small number of* "pathological" points to not impact our notion of generic behavior is usually a good idea.)

We can also ask "local" versions of Q1 above:

> Q2: Suppose $U$ is $\tau$-open (and nonempty!). For which properties $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$ is the set $$S_\varphi^U:=\{x\in U: \varphi(x)\}$$ $\tau_U$-comeager, where $\tau_U=\{W\cap U: W\in\tau\}$ is the subspace topology on $U$ coming from $\tau$?

The point is this:

### We now have a forcing relation!

Specifically, for $U$ an open subset of $\mathcal{T}$ and $\varphi$ a property in $\mathscr{P}$, we write $U\Vdash \varphi$ iff the set $S_\varphi^U$ is $\tau_U$-comeager. **Note that there is no negation in sight** ... yet.

Now let's make two assumptions about $\mathscr{P}$.

Our first assumption is forcing-related; effectively, this says that we have a "truth=forcing" result:

> **Assumption 1**: There is a $\tau$-comeager set $C\subseteq X$ such that for every $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$ and every $x\in C$ there is an open $U\ni x$ such that every $y\in C\cap U$ has $\varphi(y)\leftrightarrow \varphi(x)$.

Our second assumption is "syntactic" in a sense, and says that $\mathscr{P}$ satisfies a mild closure property:

> **Assumption 2**: $\mathscr{P}$ is *closed under negation*, that is, for every property $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$ there is a $\psi\in\mathscr{P}$ such that $$S_\psi=X\setminus S_\varphi.$$ (We'll write $\neg\varphi$ for such a $\psi$.)

(Now you might wonder why I'm talking about properties at all instead of just sets of points, and that's a fair question; in my opinion, talking about properties keeps the intuition clearer, but that's subjective.)

Again, I want to stress that *negation has so far only appeared on the "properties" side of things*. The behavior of negation on the forcing side of things is now a provable result:

> **Claim**: Let $C$ be as in assumption $1$, and let $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$. Then for every nonempty $\tau$-open set $U\subseteq X$ the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $U\Vdash\neg\varphi$.
> 2. There is no nonempty $\tau$-open $W\subseteq U$ such that $W\Vdash\varphi$.

*Proof*: Immediately from the definition we see that forcing is *monotonic*, in the sense that if $U$ and $V$ are nonempty $\tau$-open sets with $U\supseteq V$ then $U\Vdash\varphi\implies W\Vdash\varphi$ for every $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$. This gives us $1\rightarrow 2$.

For $2\rightarrow 1$, note that if $2$ holds then by assumption $1$ there cannot be any $x\in U\cap C$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds (otherwise take the $W$ as given by assumption $1$ and consider $U\cap W$). But this means that $S^U_\varphi$ is $\tau_U$-comeager, that is, $U\Vdash \varphi$. $\quad\Box$

The point is this:

### The logical structure of $\Vdash$, as developed here, simply recapitulates the logical properties of $\mathscr{P}$ (e.g. closure under negation)

At this point I can give the precise connection between the topological picture above and the standard set-theoretic picture of forcing with a (nontrivial) poset $\mathbb{P}$ over a c.t.m. $M$:

- $X$ is the set of all maximal filters through $\mathbb{P}$, and $\tau$ is the topology on $X$ generated by $\{\{G\in X: p\in G\}: p\in\mathbb{P}\}$.
- $C$ is the set of all points in $X$ which are $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$.

Of course, neither $X$ nor $C$ is an element of $M$ (indeed, $C\cap M=\emptyset$), but who cares?

- $\mathscr{P}$ is then the set of properties of the form $$M[G]\models\varphi$$ for $\varphi$ a sentence in the first-order forcing language in the usual sense.

Note, of course, that assumption 1 (in any particular case including the set-theoretic one) **requires proof**. But this is exactly what the forcing theorem does, at least for $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathscr{P}$ of the above form.

Comment: Apologies, I can't work out what either Assumption 1 or 2 is doing. 

**About Assumption 1 :** 

Should it be "..that for each $\varphi$ **there exists** an x $\in$ C which gives ...." (i.e. there will always be at least one x that will be able to have $\varphi$ true in $\mathscr{P}$)?

What does $\varphi(y)\leftrightarrow \varphi(x)$ mean ? Does it refer to when $\varphi$ is true and when $\varphi$ is not true ? Or is it that they take on the same truth value (which is true).

How is it related to "truth=forcing" ?

Comment: @LittleCheese No, assumption 1 is **correct as written**: *every* $x$ in $C$ has the relevant property. Meanwhile, "$\varphi(y)\leftrightarrow\varphi(x)$" means that $y$ has property $\varphi$ iff $x$ does. Basically, assumption 1 is saying that all the properties we care about - on a comeager set, at least! - look "locally constant." The connection with forcing is that open sets (essentially) correspond to forcing conditions, points in $X$ are maximal filters (generic or not!), $C$ is the set of (sufficiently) generic filters, and $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of sentences in the forcing language.

Comment: *(This is spelled out at the end of my answer.)* That is, assumption 1 says: for each sufficiently-generic point (= for each point $x$ in $C$), any property we care about (= any $\varphi\in\mathscr{P}$) that holds of $x$ in fact holds of all sufficiently-generic points near $x$ (= all $y\in C\cap U$ for some open $U\ni x$), and any property we care about that fails of $x$ in fact fails of all sufficiently-generic points near $x$. Similarly, "truth=forcing" says "if $G$ is sufficiently generic and $\varphi$ holds of $G$ then for some $p\in G$ $\varphi$ holds of all sufficiently generic $H\ni p$

Comment: I think I may have finally worked out what your Assumption 1 is doing. So is the following correct (using Kunen) -

Definition of $\Vdash$ :

$p \Vdash \varphi \; \text{ iff } \; \forall G \; [(G \text{ is } \mathbb{P} \text{-Generic }  \land p \in G) \implies (M[G]\models\varphi[G])]  \tag{1} $

The Forcing Truth Theorem is (taking $\Vdash^*$ to be the same as $\Vdash$), with G $\mathbb{P}$-Generic :

Comment: $ \forall \varphi \; \forall G \; [(M[G]\models\varphi[G]) \leftrightarrow (\exists p \in G ) \;  p \Vdash \varphi)]   \tag{2} $

So, inserting (1) into rhs of (2) and taking G to be $\mathbb{P}$-Generic :

 
$ \forall \varphi \; \forall G \;  [(M[G]\models\varphi[G]) \leftrightarrow ((\exists p \in G ) \;  \forall G' \ni p  \; (M[G']\models\varphi[G']))]   \tag{3} $

Comment: Since Assumption 1 just considers the true ("x has Property") cases (Assumption 2 addresses negation) then (3) can be modified to be, with G $\mathbb{P}$-Generic:

$ \forall \varphi \; \forall G \; \exists p \in G \; \forall G' \ni p \; [(M[G]\models\varphi[G]) \; \leftrightarrow  \; (M[G']\models\varphi[G'])]   \tag{4} $

Comment: Am I right in thinking there is an issue with **Claim** ? To prove **Claim**, Assumption 1 is not needed (it is only needed to link Topology definition of $\Vdash$ to $\models$ in the last part of the answer). What is needed to prove **Claim** are the properties of comeager (big sets, true) and meager (small sets, false). So choosing the definition of generic as comeager is indispensable (along with assuming classical logic). So :

Comment: $ [U \Vdash \neg \varphi] \; \text{  iff  } \;  [S^U_\neg\varphi:=\{x\in U: \neg \varphi(x)\} \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \; [S^U_\neg\varphi=(U\setminus S^U_\varphi) \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \; [S^U_\varphi \text{ is meager}]$

Since all open subsets of a meager set are meager (subsets of a small set are still small) then, thankfully (for consitency):

Comment: $ [U \Vdash \neg \varphi] \; \implies \;  \forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi]    $

For the reverse implication, note first :

$ \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi] \; \text{  iff  } \; \neg \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \;  \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is meager}]\; \text{  iff  } \; [S^W_\neg\varphi=(W\setminus S^W_\varphi) \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \; [W \Vdash \neg \varphi]  $

Comment: This looks to be 'like' the Tarski Truth definition for structures since it is:

$ [W \Vdash \neg \varphi]   \text{  iff  } \; \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi] \; \tag{1}$

However Forcing with a p $\in \mathbb{P}$ does not obey this rule, since its possible for $ [\neg (p \Vdash \neg \varphi)   \land \; \neg \; (p \Vdash \varphi)] \; $i.e. 

$ \text{ not true } [(p \Vdash \neg \varphi)   \iff \; \neg \; (p \Vdash \varphi)] \; \tag{2}$

Comment: Anyway, continuing on with the reverse implication:

$ [(\forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi]) \;  \text{  iff  } \; (\forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \; [W \Vdash \neg \varphi])] \; \implies [U \Vdash \neg \varphi] $

So the Forcing definition of negation (e.g. Kunen) is not equivalent to the 'Topological Forcing' definition due to (1) and (2), if the intention is to treat W as in some way equivalent to a p $\in \mathbb{P}$ (eg if W:={G : p $\in$ G}).

Comment: @LittleCheese I don't follow your argument. In particular, a quantifier around $W$ seems to have disappeared. Meanwhile it is definitely **not** true that we have $U\not\Vdash\varphi$ iff $U\Vdash\neg\varphi$ in the sense of my post: take, for example, our topological space to be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, $\varphi$ to be "is $>0$," and $U=(-1,1)$. Then $U$ does not force either $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$. So I disagree with your claim that there's a difference here.

Comment: On your first point the only place I can see that there are quantifiers is : $ [(\forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi]) \;  \text{  iff  } \; (\forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \; [W \Vdash \neg \varphi])] \; \implies [U \Vdash \neg \varphi] $.  I think the RHS needs no quantifier as that's the case with W=U ?

Comment: Ooh, spotted another one, though $ [U \Vdash \neg \varphi] \; \implies \;  \forall \text{ open } \; W \subseteq U \; \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi]    $ doesn't look to need any extra quantifiers as the $\forall$ comed from all open subsets of a meager set are meager ?

Comment: @LittleCheese I think there might be a formatting glitch here - your formulas are displaying oddly on my end (I think "\mbox" might make things worse?), and there are some blanks that suggest certain symbols not rendering. So ignore that for now. Regardless, the actual substantive point is my observation that the $\Vdash$ of my answer does **not** satisfy the property $U\not\Vdash\varphi\implies U\Vdash\neg\varphi$ that you claim.

Comment: You may well be right ! I just learned a bit about Topology to try to understand your response.... I also guessed what $S_\psi=X\setminus S_\varphi$ was when U is X. So there must be something wrong with $ \neg \; [W \Vdash \varphi] \; \text{  iff  } \; \neg \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \;  \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is meager}]\; \text{  iff  } \; [S^W_\neg\varphi=(W\setminus S^W_\varphi) \text{ is comeager}] \; \text{  iff  } \; [W \Vdash \neg \varphi]  $ ??

Comment: In your previous comment (specifically, the second "iff") you seem to be assuming that a set is not comeager iff it is meager. This is blatantly false - for example, in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology the interval $(-1,1)$ is neither meager nor comeager.

Comment: Ah, I see that the left to right implication doesn't always hold : so its not always true that $\neg \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is comeager}] \; \implies \;  \; [S^W_\varphi:=\{x\in W: \varphi(x)\} \text{ is meager}]$. Will spend a few weeks getting more familiar with Topology and Boolean-valued models. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I need a hint on **Claim** $2\rightarrow 1$. I am assuming that your **remarkable (ie $\varphi(x)$ doesnt hold for any x $\in$ U)** proof wording, allowing for typos is : 

For $2\rightarrow 1$, note that if $2$ holds then by assumption $1$ there cannot be any $x\in U\cap C$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds (otherwise take the $W$ as given by assumption $1$ and consider $U\cap W$). But this means that $S^U_\varphi$ is meager, that is, $U\Vdash \neg \varphi$.

Comment: I can't work out what the definition of $W\Vdash \varphi$ is in relation to Assumption 1 - there is no G (ie x) mentioned in $W\Vdash \varphi$ - is it $W\Vdash \varphi \iff \forall y,z \in W \; (\varphi(y) \leftrightarrow  \varphi(z)) $ ? As a result I can't see what $2$ is doing to lead to the remarkable result that $\varphi(x)$ doesn't hold for any x $\in$ U ($\cap \; C$).

Comment: @LittleCheese "$W\Vdash\varphi$" means exactly what "$U\Vdash\varphi$" means, just with $W$ replacing $U$: it means that $\varphi(x)$ holds for comeager-in-$W$-many $x$s (that is, $S^W_\varphi$ is $\tau_W$-comeager).

Comment: That said, I have fixed a couple typos.

Comment: Is my attempt to prove **Claim**  $2\rightarrow 1$ correct ? : 

Assumption 1 gives, fixing $\varphi$, C comeager in X : 

$\forall x \in (U \cap C) \; \exists \text{ open } W_x \ni x : \forall y \in (W_x \cap C) : (\varphi(y) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x)) \tag{1}$

Comment: So fixing x $\in$ U, taking $U \cap W_x$ gives .... ?. How big is $W_x$, $(W_x \cap C)$, $(U \cap C)$, $(W_x \cap U)$? Assume the intersection of a comeager set (C) in X and an open set $W_x$ in $\tau_X$ always gives a comeager subset Z of $W_x$ (I couldn't find out whether this is correct on stackexchange or even the web - no results were returned - any ideas where there would be a reference for the proof - if its true ?). Taking $(U \cap W_x$) = an open subset of U, call it V. Taking $V \cap Z$ will then give a comeager subset of V.

Comment: However **Claim** item $2$ says that there are no open subsets V of U having a comeager subset with property $\varphi$. Since (1) above has two possible solutions $\varphi(x)$ holds or $\varphi(x)$ doesnt hold, then $\varphi(x)$ must not hold. This is, remarkably, true for all $x \in U \cap C$. As $U \cap C$ is comeager in "$\varphi$ doesn't hold" this means that $U \Vdash \neg \varphi$.

Answer (score 2):

Like many foundational aspects of forcing, this makes more sense (to me) if we think first about Boolean-valued models. In that context, formulas $A$ have truth values $\Vert A\Vert$ in a completeBoolean algebra $\mathcal B$, and the propositional connectives for formulas correspond to the Boolean operations in $\mathcal B$. In particular, propositional negation $\neg$ corresponds to Boolean complement: $\Vert\neg A\Vert=-\Vert A\Vert$.

The transition from Boolean-valued models to forcing consists of working not with the complete Boolean algebra $\mathcal B$ but with a dense subset $P$ of its non-zero part $\mathcal B-\{0\}$. ("Dense" means that each non-zero element of $\mathcal B$ is $\geq$ some element of $P$.) Instead of talking about elements $b\in\mathcal B$, one talks about $\{p\in P:p\leq b\}$. In particular, one says that $p$ forces $A$ and one writes $p\Vdash A$ iff $p\leq\Vert A\Vert$.

So to describe "forcing $\neg A$" in terms of "forcing $A$", we must figure out how to express (for elements $p\in P$) that $p\leq-b$ in terms of $p\leq b$.

It is an easy exercise in Boolean algebra to show that, for any elements of any Boolean algebra, we have $p\leq-b$ iff $0$ is the only element $c$ that simultaneously satisfies $c\leq p$ and $c\leq b$.

Finally, using the fact that $P$ is dense in $\mathcal B-\{0\}$, we find that the $c$ in this criterion can be understood as ranging only over $P$ (and then $0$ is no longer an exception, since $0\notin P$) without any change in the meaning. So we get $p\leq-b$ iff no element $q\in P$ simultaneously satisfies $q\leq p$ and $q\leq b$. In particular, taking $\Vert A\Vert$ as $b$, we get that $p\Vdash\neg A$ iff no $q\leq p$ in $P$ satisfies $q\Vdash A$.

Answer (score 0):

Some partial answers:

For (iv), consider the following:$$(*)\forall k [(\exists k'' \geq k : (k'' \Vdash ¬A)) \Longleftarrow  \forall k′ \geq k \;  \neg \; (k′ \Vdash A)]$$ This  implies
$$\forall k\{k' \geq k :(k' \Vdash A) \; OR \;  (k' \Vdash \neg A)\}$$ is dense below $k$.  So if you mean in (*) in (iv), then (iv) works.

For (i), I think Cohen wants   truth in the forcing extension M[G] can be forced in the ground model M, that is, for any given A, whether M[G]\models A can be decided in M. That is exactly what the forcing theorem says. Since  $M[G]\models A$ or $\neg A$ is true, without loss of generality, assume M[G]\models A, then for any condition $p$ and any generic filter $G$ containing $p$, there must be some stronger $q$ forces $A$.

For (ii), first note the book  of either Kunen's or Cohen's is working under first-order logic. Secondly      note the  difference between the two notions of  forcing. Kunen and Cohen's book  are talking set-theoretic forcing in Set Theory under first-order logic. Set-theoretic forcing is merely a tool helping us extending   set-theoretic model(structure)s.  Validity in first-order logic has nothing to do with set-theoretic forcing ($A$ is valid if $M\models A$ for any structure $M$).  But validity  in intuitionistic is depend on (defined by) forcing (see page 97 in the second reference you cited.
).  You may find a poof of the non-intuitionistic validity of ($A$ or $\neg A$) in  page 97-98 in the second reference you cited.

I do not understand your question in (iii). What do you mean "forcing is consistent" ?

Comment: Thanks Hang Zhang. I am interested to see why (iv) : $$\exists k'' \geq k : (k'' \Vdash ¬A) \Longleftarrow  \forall k′ \geq k \;  \neg \; (k′ \Vdash A)$$ doesn't work - it looks to create a negation complete generic set. In Cohen's book the proof "Lemma 5 A is true in N iff for some k , k forces A" would go through using (iv). [Also presumably you meant $\models$ instead of $\Vdash$ in your answer.].

Comment: @ Hang Zhang. Also what about the strange results in (i), (ii), (iii) as well? It seems like forcing has a very large amount of reasoning that isn't based upon the individual content of each element in the generic set., in order to make it negation complete (ie $M[G] \models A$ or $M[G] \models \neg A$). But does it have to be like that to make the generic negation complete and consistent ? (I suspect it does - but due to the properties of infinity and the need for the generic to be a new set).

Comment: @ Hang Zhang - thanks for your interest in the question (and my late reply). It seems like StackExchange does not notify me that you have edited your answer ! I'm giving your answers some thought.

Comment: @ Hang Zhang - Maybe on (i) you could consider the following : Let A be "G has infinitely many elements" and $\neg A$ to be "G has finitely many elements". Is it possible for the finite amount of information in any forcing condition to 'imply' (note I didn't say force) either of these statements? The answer is a definite NO. Indeed any finite forcing condition will not 'imply' an infinite number of formulae one way or another. So any p will not 'imply' an infinite number of B  : "not true (p $\implies$ B) AND not true (p $\implies \neg$ B)".

Comment: @ Hang Zhang - Also of course any p will also definitely 'imply' an infinite number of formulae C, or negated formulae $\neg$ D , using ONLY the finite information in p : {C : p $\implies$ C} and {$\neg$ D  : p $\implies \neg$ D}. Given, as you correctly say, the objective is to achieve a negation complete representation of the formulae true in M[G] in the base model M, the question is how to balance out what a condition p can and can't imply, by imposing a forced negation completeness definition in a way that doesn't create chaos and an inconsistent set of forced formulae.

Comment: @LittleCheese I learnt a lot from your questions. Following are some thoughts may be  helpful to the "reasoning behind.. " problem you posed :  (1) Set theory forcing. Suppose  there is p which  does not  force  A  and no  stronger q force the  negation of A. Then  {q: q force (A or neg A)} is  not  dense below p.  Then  no  condition in the generic filter would force  (A or neg A).  (2) In the view of a  computer verification program, we may think  of the  partial order  P  as  the  set  of all states of a  fixed  program (aiming at check truth).

Comment: Then  for every sentence A,  at every state p,  we have three cases: ONE. either we have known the truth of A ( in which case  we say p forces A); TWO.  There exists some  other state q  legally  follows after  p (in  some possible future  according to the program )  such  that we  will know the truth  of  A at q (so q force A).  THREE.  No future state q of  p  verifies  the  truth of A  in  which case we  have to  admit the negation of A  since we admit (A or neg A) is valid, in this sense, p verifies neg A, so we write  p force neg A.

Comment: (3). Now , go back to set theory forcing. In forcing extension, (A or neg A) is true since the generic filter G is a "generic realization" of the verification computer program in the sense of (2), that is, G intersects the set  {q: q force (A or neg A)}.

Comment: @ Hang Zhang - I was wondering if there is a reference for your "(2) In the view of a computer verification program, we may think of the partial order P as the set of all states of a fixed program (aiming at check truth)". I'm intrigued by the idea but I cant see why it is a fixed program directly. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See Logic for Applications by Nerode and Shore. I forgot to give the reference. Welcome!

Comment: @ Hang Zhang - would it be possible to give any clues where the statement  leading to your "(2) In the view of a computer verification program, we may think of the partial order P as the set of all states of a fixed program (aiming at check truth)" is located in Logic for Applications by Nerode and Shore. I have electronically searched it for various words like "state", program"... and still couldn't find it. I have the Second Edition. Thanks.

Comment: There are several paragraphs describing the computer background in Second Edition, see page 264 for intuitionistic logic,  and page 223 for modal logic.